# How to increase DataGrip's ability to add more lines in console

Tags: datagrip

I've got DataGrip and I would like to add some INSERT INTO statements, but I'm getting an error that says

> Content is too large (209,46 MB), limit is 20,97MB

I haven't found out how to increase that limit.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to open such a big file, it can affect performance and memory consumption. But it's on your own. Please read [this topic](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/tuning-the-ide.html#common-platform-properties). You need to increase idea.max.content.load.filesize value, just go to Help -> Edit custom properties and paste something like this:

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=250000
```